# Allegro5 makefile error

Tags: c, makefile, allegro5

note: this is the final exercise in the Head First C book.

I have the following problem. I am trying to make a game using the allegro5.2 libraries. I want to use multiple .c files in order to organize everything neatly. However, I have problems compiling my programs using a makefile. I am trying to compile this easy program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro.h>

const int disp_h = 640;
const int disp_w = 480;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display;

if(!al_init()) {
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to initialize allegro!\n");
    return -1;
}

display = al_create_display(disp_h,disp_w);
if(!display) {
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to create display!\n");
    return -1;
}

al_rest(0.4);
al_destroy_display(display);

printf("bye bye!!!\n");

return 0;
}
```

The makefile is:

```
Blasteroids.o: allegro.h Blasteroids.c
    gcc -Wall -c Blasteroids.c

Blasteroids: Blasteroids.o allegro.h
    gcc -Wall -I/usr/include/allegro5 -L/usr/lib -lallegro -lallegro_main Blasteroids.o -o Blasteroids
```

Now, when I use the terminal this compiles fine, but now I seem to have a problem. The error given by the terminal (using the command make Blasteroids) is:

```
cc   Blasteroids.o   -o Blasteroids
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_al_create_display", referenced from:
      __al_mangled_main in Blasteroids.o
  "_al_destroy_display", referenced from:
      __al_mangled_main in Blasteroids.o
  "_al_install_system", referenced from:
      __al_mangled_main in Blasteroids.o
  "_al_rest", referenced from:
      __al_mangled_main in Blasteroids.o
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
     (maybe you meant: __al_mangled_main)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Blasteroids] Error 1
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong and I am very new to these things. I have searched for examples in makefiles, but they give me code like I am using now. 
I now I can just use a single line for the above program, but the idea is that I want to make my own .c files, make them into .o files and then link them together. Hence the makefile.

Comment: I really doubt that the _exact_ same command works from the terminal.  You should move the library flags `-lallegro -lallegro_main` to the end of the link line, after the `.o` files.

Comment: It really works. I get an open screen for a moment whenever I run the program

Comment: I mean, the link command not the output program.  In any event, your libraries must come after the object files in the link line.

Comment: Well, in addition the makefile isn't being used.  You can tell that because the link command isn't the command you wrote in the makefile.  What did you name the makefile?  It must be `Makefile` or `makefile`, or else you have to use `make -f mymakefile Blasteroids` if you choose a non-standard name.

Comment: Like this: gcc -Wall -I/usr/include/allegro5 -L/usr/lib Blasteroids.o -lallegro -lallegro_main -o Blasteroids? Or also after the -o?
Anyway, my file is called makefile (I am using .txt extension however). Could that be the problem? Sorry if this seems simple but I just really want to understand this.

Comment: Yes that's the problem.  The file must be called `makefile` or `Makefile`, with no extension.  UNIX systems don't really do extensions (I mean many files have them but they're not special like they are in Windows; in UNIX if they exist they're just part of the filename).  If you want to call your makefile `makefile.txt` instead you have to use `make -f makefile.txt Blasteroids` to tell make what the name of your file is explicitly.

Comment: Regarding your other question, the order of the `-o` option doesn't matter.  The things that matter are the `-l` (library) options compared to each other and to your object files (`.o`).  Object files must all always come first before the `-l` options.

Comment: Oké, removing the extension fixed the problem. Do you want to post your solution as an answer? Else I'll accept the one down below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `make` program looks for files named `makefile` or `Makefile`, with no extension.  If you name your makefile something else, such as `makefile.txt`, then `make` can't find it and it will just use its own built-in rules which don't know anything about extra flags ro libraries that may be needed.

So either rename your makefile to `makefile` or `Makefile`, or else specify the name of your makefile explicitly on the command line when you run make, such as `make -f makefile.txt Blasteroids`.

Secondarily, if you don't specify a target on the command line then make will always build the first target.  So, if you re-order your targets so that the one you usually want to build (in this case `Blasteroids`) is first, then you can just run `make` with no arguments and it will build that target.

Unlike a programming language, the order of target definition doesn't matter to make: e.g., you don't have to define rules for all the object files first before the link line.  Make reads the entire file and constructs an internal graph of prerequisite relationships, and nodes and edges in this graph can be added in any order.

Answer (score 0):

something like the following makefile contents should do the job

Notes:

1. header files are only needed during the compile step
2. library files are only needed during the link step
3. best to have the first 'target' be 'all' so the makefile can be successfully executed without have to include a 'Blasteroids' parameter
4. having a 'target' 'clean' makes it easy to clear away the items that will be rebuilt
5. any 'target' that does not produce a file of the same name should be listed in a '.PSEUDO' operator
6. the linker processes the linker command line items in the order listed on the command line. Therefore, list the objects, then the directories, then the library 'short' names
7. list the header files at the end of the compile command line
8. use macros (like CC and RM) that contain the full path to the executables so the correct executable is used, other wise the first item found in the $PATH that matches the name will be used.
9. $^ is a built in macro that expands to the recipe dependencies
10. $< is a built in macro that expands to the first dependency
11. $@ is a built in macro that expands to the recipe 'target'
12. the `$(SRC:.c=?)` statements do character replacement on the extension of the file names contained in the `$(SRC)` macro
13. the `%.o:%.c` recipe says for each source file to be compiled into a object file, use this recipe
14. the '-ggdb' is so the maximum debug information will be available to the 'gdb' debugger.
15. this pattern of 'makefile' can be extensively used for other projects with only minor variations.  For more flexibility could also insert a recipe for automatically generating the header file dependencies, so would not need to list them individually in the compile recipe, but for now, the following makefile contents will do what you are currently trying to perform

and now the makefile

```
CC := /bin/gcc
RM := /bin/rm

CFLAGS := -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=gnu99 -ggdb -c
LFLAGS := -L/usr/lib -lallegro -lallegro_main

SRC    := Blasteroids.c
#OBJ    := $(SRC:.c=.0)
OBJ    := $(SRC:.c=.o)
NAME   := $(SRC:.c=)

.PSEUDO: all clean

all: $(NAME)

%.o:%.c
    #$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@ -I/usr/include/allegro5
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@ -I/usr/include/allegro5

$(NAME): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -ggdb  $^ -o $@  $(LFLAGS)

.clean:
    $(RM) -f $(NAME) $(OBJ)
```

Comment: You should definitely not use `$^` in your compile rule, you should use `$<`.  Also, your setting of `OBJ` is not right (you're adding `.0` not `.o`).  I recommend using the standard variables, which means `LDFLAGS` for linker flags like `-L` and `LDLIBS` for libraries like `-l`.  Personally I recommend against using fully-qualified paths for `CC` and `RM`.

Comment: @MadScientist, I agree with correcting keypunch errors that you mentioned. However, when more than one executable has the same name, If the executable that you want the makefile to use is not the first one found in cache or in the $PATH list, then the wrong one will be executed. That is why should always use 'fully-qualified' paths for any OS functions, like gcc and rm and mv and chgrp and chmod and ... the standard macros: 'LDFLAGS' and 'LDLIBS' may not be exactly what you want in your makefile.  So you would be replacing them anyway.  Best to replace with unique macro names.

Comment: Ill edit my answer to reflect the corrections to the keypunch errors,  Note: a leading `#` in a makefile line means the line is comments only

Comment: You should use comment characters in column 1, not after the TAB, in a recipe line.  GNU make doesn't treat comment characters appearing in recipe lines specially, so that command will be passed to the shell as a command to run (the shell will treat it as a comment since it uses the same character).

Comment: The purpose of the standard variables is to allow users to override the variable settings to modify how the makefile rules behave.  IMO it's always better/more correct to re-use the standard variables (for their intended uses, of course, which these are) rather than invent new variables that people aren't familiar with and aren't sure how to use.  Also, certainly I'm familiar with PATH and what it does; it's better to let the user use PATH to configure their system.  Maybe a system has `/usr/bin/rm` and not `/bin/rm`: now your makefile breaks for no good reason.  However, of course YMMV.

Comment: if the OS has a non standard configuration, then their makefiles need to be updated to match that non standard configuration.    If the makefile is to be used in both standard and non standard platforms then the make file should be expanded to check which configuration it is being run on.

Comment: As I said, I strongly disagree: this is one of the main purposes behind PATH, to allow these differences to be accommodated without a lot of hassle.  If you're really concerned about using the "wrong" versions (but why is it wrong if the user set up their PATH to use them?  Isn't that their prerogative?) then you can add something like `PATH := /bin:$(PATH)` to your makefile so that the versions in `/bin` will always be chosen first if they exist.  Anyway, it's up to you how you want to do things.  I don't agree, but they're your makefiles.